# how userid and password exposed in network in sql authentication

Tags: sql-server-2008, security, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-authentication, sql-authentication

How is the userid and password  exposed on the network in SQL authentication and why doesn't this happen in Windows authentication?

Answer (score 1):

In Windows authentication, SQL verifies the security token created for the user when they logged into their Windows machine, and never actually requires the password.  If you connect to a remote SQL server with SQL Authentication, you have to submit a password, and you are then depemdant on the network communication to be secure.